# Nelson & Siegel model (Fixed Income Securities)

Tags: fixed-income, bond, bond-yields, statistical-finance

I am well aware of the basic model formula and for what it is used, theoretically speaking, however I cannot find any concrete, problem solving exercises.

Soon, I will have to deal with this problem on the fixed Income exam ( paper&pen form). Some colleges from the previous generation of students have mentioned that something need to be integrated.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

PS. I feel uncomfortable asking such an ambiguous question, but in classes we haven't had the time to cover it thoroughly, and my lecture notes concerning Nelson & Siegel model are pretty vague.

Comment: Have you read the original paper? https://cepr.org/sites/default/files/events/1854_NS_1987.pdf It has examples.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice survey of how this model and its alternatives are used by the central banks:

https://www.bis.org/publ/bppdf/bispap25a.pdf